# How big of a lens or parabolic mirror would it take

Tags: optics

...to heat a piece of steel so its glowing yellow (1100 C)? Assuming you had a cloudless day at a latitude of, say, San Francisco...

Basically I'm wondering if it is possible/feasible to be able to do basic metal working without a traditional forge, just using the power of the sun to heat the metal. So the diameter of the heated spot would have to be about 6" in order to heat a large enough area of the metal to work it...

I always thought you would need several huge pieces of equipment to do this, but just thought I'd ask if anyone here knew how to figure out it roughly...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For steel, the specific heat would be $c_p=0.5 kJ/kg K$, with a density of $
\rho=7000 kg/m^3$. Suppose you want to increase the temperature bij say $\Delta T=1100K$ of a piece of size $V=(15cm)^3$

Then you would need a total energy of.

$$E=\rho c_p V \Delta T$$
Which gives you typically $E=10^7 J$

Now, the power of the sun on a bright day, would be of the order of $p=10^3 W/m^2$.

Assuming that

- all the energy input is converted into heat
- the mirror is perfectly aligned
- no heat is lost during heating,
- no melting, e.g. no latent heat

and your mirror had diameter $D$ and you let the process run for a time $t$, then

$$E=p \frac{\pi}{4}D^2 t $$

Then you will get, in approximation

$$D = \sqrt{\frac{E}{pt}}$$

So, suppose you are willing to wait for ten minutes, then the mirror diameter would be $D\approx 4m$. Considering we assumed an ideal system, this is only an order of magnitude assumption.

Comment: One should also take into consideration whether the supplied power is sufficient to heat up the steel more while energy is lost due to thermal radiation. Assuming that it is a black body, we have $P=\sigma T^4A$ where $T=1500\textrm{ K}$, $\sigma=5.67\times 10^{−8}\textrm{ Wm}^{-2}\textrm{K}^{-4}$ and $A\approx 0.1\textrm{ m}^2$ which gives us $P=2.9\times10^4\textrm{ W}$. In other words, in order to _keep_ it at such a temperature, we need $D \geq 6\textrm{ m}$. This is obviously a rather close call, as this power is _absolutely required_, while the power supplied is more of an upper bond.

Comment: @Claudius, I assumed no heat losses, so the $4m$ is probably an absolute lower bound. But including it would demand solving a differential equation in time, as you reach a asymptotic temperature, didn't think it was necessary for an order of magnitude estimation. Only time $t$ is rather arbitrarily chosen in my estimation here.

Comment: If you still want to get the time $t$, you indeed have to solve a differential equation. However, if you ignore $t$ (i. e. $t \to \infty$) you can get an upper bound on the temperature reachable with a specific diametre (as given in my calculation above). Not including heat loss would effectively mean that if one waited long enough, _any_ mirror would do.

Comment: @Claudius You are absolutely right.